# How Do I use jquery to get each value from a cshtml foreach loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building a staff appraisal system, where users are asked 10 questions in order to appraise an employee. Something like this [image: Staff Appraisal]

Each star is assigned a value between 1 - 5. I am currently getting each value, but how do I assign each value to a variable like: `var questionOne = 2; var questionTwo = 3;`

This is my code so far:

```html
<h4>Score Ola using our rating form below.</h4>
<p>Job Title: Nanny</p>
<p style="color: red; font-size: 12px;">
  Note: Questions are selected based on job title. We are constantly reviewing the list of job specific questions, please assist by recommending questions you would like to add to our job specific questionaire <a href="#">here</a>
</p>
@foreach (var question in Model.AppraisalQuestions)
{
  <p>@question.QuestionDescription</p>
  <div class="row lead evaluation">
    <div id="colorstar" class="starrr ratable"></div>
    <span id="count">0</span> star(s) - <span id="meaning"> </span>
  </div><br />
}
```

The Javascript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var correspondence = ["", "Poor", "Below Expectation", "Above Expectation", "Good", "Excelent" ];
  $('.ratable').on('starrr:change', function(e, value) {
    $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('#count').html(value);
    $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('#meaning').html(correspondence[value]);
    var currentval =  $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('#count').html();
    var target =  $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('.indicators');
    target.css("color","black");
    target.children('.rateval').val(currentval);
    target.children('#textwr').html(' ');
    alert(value);
  });
```

I want to store each score in a database. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This would most likely resolve in duplication of ID's and that should be avoided.

Comment: Its not clear what you are wanting to solve - you are not binding anything to your model. Are you wanting to set the initial values, or is your issue trying to update the values?

Comment: @stephen thanks, I want to get each rating for each question, and store it in a database...

Comment: Are the AppraisalQuestions always 5 items?

Comment: But you do not have a form, or any form controls to post back. And what jquery plugin are you using for the rating control (if any)?

Comment: @ gardarvalur yes the appraisal ratings are always 5, while the questions will always be 10....

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will use a jquery post to post it, but I'm stuck at getting each score for each question....

Comment: It makes no difference if its posted using ajax. You should be binding to your model - at the least you model will contain an `int Rating` property that you bind to and then you can serialize your form to post it

Comment: Yeah, I understand, I have a model, the issue I am having is how to get the value of each rating using jquery, before passing it to my rating model.

Comment: How about assigning it from the Model as such, <div id="colorstar" class="starrr ratable" data-value="@question.derp"></div> ---> where derp is your value

Comment: Ok...Thanks, but I'm a bit confused....will it get the value for each rating?

Comment: hmmm.... now that I look at your code more closely it seems as you will only show one star per each iteration of the loop.  Shouldn´t you have five stars within each iteration?

Comment: I don't Understand ur question please...

Comment: I´ll attempt to answer you

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstaing your question completely but this pseudo code works for me. I added five empty stars to each question and assigned value and questionID to each.  You should be able to change the star icon via jQuery too but I didn´t include that.

Just let me know if I am misunderstanding.

Markup code:

```
@foreach (var question in Model.AppraisalQuestions)
{
    <p>@question.QuestionDescription</p>
    <div class="row lead evaluation">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty starrr ratable" data-value="1" data-question="@question.QuestionID"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty starrr ratable" data-value="2" data-question="@question.QuestionID"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty starrr ratable" data-value="3" data-question="@question.QuestionID"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty starrr ratable" data-value="4" data-question="@question.QuestionID"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty starrr ratable" data-value="5" data-question="@question.QuestionID"></i><br />
        <span class="count">0</span> star(s) - <span class="meaning"> </span>
    </div><br />
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var correspondence = ["", "Poor", "Below Expectation", "Above Expectation", "Good", "Excelent"];
        $(".ratable").click(function() {
            var value = $(this).data("value");
            var questionID = $(this).data("question");
            $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('.count').text(value);
            $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('.meaning').html(correspondence[value]);

            //TODO: send value and questionID to server, perhaps via ajax or something
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Cool, @user8107351 perhaps you´ll let me know if it works?  :)